# Application stuck while presenting new VC in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to present a new VC, but when I hit the code application get stuck and I can't do anything. It's quite a weird issue, how can I get out of it? My code for presenting new VC is this,

```
let vc : PropertyDetailController! =
        UIStoryboard.viewController(identifier: "PropertyDetailController", storyBoard: "Explore") as? PropertyDetailController

    vc.propertyDetailData = property
    vc.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true
    vc.modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve
    vc.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
    self.navigationController?.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

This is what it shows in console,

```
Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKitCore/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

It isn't present new VC. This is how it my apps stuck please check gif link,
[enter link description here](https://imgflip.com/gif/3ff05x)

Comment: can you please add gif ?

Comment: I have added gif please check. @YogeshPatel

Comment: It seems you are moving to new storyboard and I think you need UINavigationController to handle this like `let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: "YOUR_VC")
    self.presentViewController(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)`

Comment: Yeah, this code is working fine, please mention this in answer. @MaulikPandya

Comment: When ever you are present any VC then make sure that you give navigationcontroller rootVC..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can see in your code you are moving to the new storyboard so it's necessary to move it on through the `UINavigationController`

Blow one is the sample code that might help you

```
let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "YOUR_STORYBOARD", bundle: nil)
let aVC: YOUR_VC = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "YOUR_VC_ID") as! YOUR_VC
let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: aVC)
self.present(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

First make sure current view controller embedded with Navigation Controller.

Now use below code to fix this issue.

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Explore", bundle: nil)

        guard let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PropertyDetailController") as? PropertyDetailController else {return}
        vc.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true
        vc.modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve
        vc.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
        self.navigationController?.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

[image]

Comment: I have tried your code but facing same issue. @Abhishek jangid

Comment: I have open same VC with a push which is working fine, but when i present same VC it get stuck. @Abhishek jangid

Comment: May I know from this code have you manage to open PropertyDetailController ?
Because I think there must be some issue in your next view controller file code.

Comment: @Hamza please check image link I have added in my code below. You need not to add any navigation controller linked with your PropertyDetailController and set their identifier accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to present a view controller, try
`self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)`

if you want to push a view controller, try
`self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)`

Comment: I have tried but facing same issue app get stuck. @Chính Quang

Comment: I have open same VC with a push which is working fine, but when i present same VC it get stuck . @Chinh Quang

Comment: hidesBottomBarWhenPushed is  boolean value indicating whether the toolbar at the bottom of the screen is hidden when the view controller is pushed on to a navigation controller. So if you want to present a view controller, that line is unnecessary

Comment: can you give more specific about that stuck ? It is glitchy or cannnot be shown completely?

Comment: It's quite simple, i have a collection view and when i click on cell i want to open detail of that, now when i push view controller or navigate through segue it works fine, and when i present VC it get stuck. @Chinh Quang

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the push code to **main thread**,

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {[weak self] in
    self?.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
}
```

Either present or push, all the UI handling must be done on the main thread.

**Edit:**

If you want to present `vc`, use

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {[weak self] in
    self?.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Still, it is facing same issue it does not present and got stuck. @PGDev

Comment: Have you used push instead of present?

Comment: Yes, with push it work fine, but when i present it get stuck. @PGDev

Comment: i have tried this also but not working same stuck issue. @PGDev

Comment: Is there any message displayed in console regarding that. Check if you've set the storyboard id to PropertyDetailController.